# Finding Patterns in Encrypted Data

Tags: cryptanalysis

I am looking for an application (Windows) or code example that might help me find patterns in an encrypted file.  I have a ciphertext for which I want to see when a key is repeated.  I am not trying to break the encryption - just test for when a pattern repeats if it does so.

I've searched, but haven't found anything yet.

Thanks.!

Comment: If you find a pattern that is considered breaking the cipher (or just a broken cipher), by many definitions.

Comment: If the encryption uses proper IVs, key re-use won't harm (the defender). You probably won't even notice IV reuse as it's unlikely that in your file the plaintexts repeat..

Comment: Let's restate the problem for two parties. Consider a prover that knows  both pattern and the text, and a verifier only having commitments (that hide plaintext just like encryption). Such a prover can efficiently convince a verifier there is a repeated pattern in the text. IACR preprint 2008/357.

Comment: I understand that while that IS technically considered breaking the cipher, until the attacker can actually read/use the plaintext - they haven't really accomplished anything. Anyway, that said, I am testing different IVs, key lengths and patterns and trying to test for repeating keys. Surely someone has already created something that can take a file and search for repeating patterns.  Why reinvent :)  Thanks everyone.